# I can't see the output when I change my orientation on device in Android

Tags: android

In my project I am able to render pdf and my problem is when I am opening a page and changing my orientation the application is crashing in the emulator. When I check it on device it is opening the home page. How can I overcome this problem?

When I open a page I want to see the same page when I change the orientation.

Comment: When it crashes in the emulator, what does the log say? What does the callstack say?

Comment: in log im getting the following things......
expected resume of com.bookreader while already resumed in com.bookreader
surfaceDestroyed(): dying
6544): stopRendering
ad( 6544): RenderThread woken up
 shutting down.
 ViewThread woken up
 shutting down
 onOrientationChanged, rotation changed to 3 false  mLockedRotation=0
 Overwriting rotation value from 3
 Rotation changed to 3 from 0 (forceApp=-1, req=3)
 Setting rotation to 3, animFlags=0
: Surface Flinger::setOrientation  mIsRotationPossible = 0, nBackupOrientationValue = 3
: setTvoutOrientation rotation =  3
: SetOrientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically when you change orientation, it will restart activity. So you have to store your state in orientation change.

You can get better info, go through [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

Comment: k thank you..Actually i am new to android, so there a little confusion for me..I want to know whether i should make changes in my androidmnifest.xml and shold write a method in my activity class and have to restore the object?

Comment: if you want to set layout for both orientation so u want to write method to save state and you have to override method @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) as above link suggests.otherwise you can set anrdoir:orientation attribute to fix value if you do not want to set fix layout for both

Comment: kk thank you shah ...in my project in portrait mode i am scaling the pdf to height and in land scape mode i want to scale the  pdf to width..so is it necesary  to change my layouts ?  thanks shah for responding to my queries...........

Comment: ya if you want to scaling so you want to implement layout for it in folder named layout-land with same name as ur default name of layout in layout folder,

Comment: kk. thank you ...i will implement and let u know if i had any issues.

Comment: if you feel this ans as useful,make this right by clicking right side of que.so people will get help of this

Comment: i am rendering my pdf on surface view so kindly let me know if there are any methods to see the output when i change the orientation without implementing seperate layout for each orientation.

Comment: if you are not using any layout and drawing view programatically by extending view than you dont need to implement it but you have to somehow find tht orientaion which is and according it you have to set view's height and width

Comment: once again thank you shah.. i have tried by taking seperate layouts for portrait and landscape and i have changed in android manifest.xml , took seperate drawable folders also but my application is crashed and i am getting the error in log as Runtime java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget  ......can u suggest any changes to make.........

Comment: in log im getting the following things...... expected resume of com.bookreader while already resumed in com.bookreader surfaceDestroyed(): dying 6544): stopRendering ad( 6544): RenderThread woken up shutting down. ViewThread woken up shutting down onOrientationChanged, rotation changed to 3 false mLockedRotation=0 Overwriting rotation value from 3 Rotation changed to 3 from 0 (forceApp=-1, req=3) Setting rotation to 3, animFlags=0 : Surface Flinger::setOrientation mIsRotationPossible = 0, nBackupOrientationValue = 3 : setTvoutOrientation rotation = 3 : SetOrientation – user493244 22 hours ago